# How to make jQuery load() not freeze the page?

Tags: jquery, load

When using jquery's load function, the page freezes until it has loaded.

How can I get around that?

I have a script that makes all links load through ajax, into a div in the page. I also made it so that it would make another div reload (the navigator).

Whilst this is going on, another script refreshes every now and then, reloading another div.

But if I stay on the page, and the one that refreshes every now and then 'reloads', the page shall freeze until it has loaded.

It's the same behaviour with the others too.

Comment: Explaining what you are doing, and giving sample code, will certainly increase your chances of an answer that gives you the solution first time :)

Comment: That's odd behaviour, could you direct us to the page so we can take a peek? Seeing the code being used will be the only way we can help here, I think.

Comment: I couldn't replicate this in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari. Looks like it might be a browser issue - which browser/version are you using? Has anyone else noticed this problem?

Comment: i'm using Firefox 3.5.3 on a Mac. Not that I know of.

Comment: Does it matter if I put the script that makes links open through ajax load(), more than once on the page?

Comment: Try it now. It freezes safari completely at some points.

Comment: Er, unlesss vapurl.com is your actual site, your vapurl has vaporised. Could you post the full link or a tinyurl?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this depends heavily on what exactly you are doing in the load() event.  If the answer is "nothing", that will require different measures than if the answer is "walking a 1,000-element DOM tree."  I'm going to guess that you are doing *something* in the load event.  Improving performance will be a matter of refactoring and deferring processing as much as possible.

It would also be helpful to know which browser you're using.  Different browsers respond to javascript very differently.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [AJAX Load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)? If you have this placed at the top of your page, and that page has other HTML elements to it which don't need to be loaded in, consider placing the JavaScript at the bottom of the page, so it is the last thing to be loaded.